# Load automatic Class HttpFoundation\Response

Tags: php, symfony

I have an controller:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\HelloBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
//use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
class HelloController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($name)
    {
        return new Response('<html><body>Hello '.$name.'!</body></html>');
    }
}
```

When I run the driver returns the error

> 1/1 ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "Response" from
>   namespace "Acme\HelloBundle\Controller" in
>   D:\symfony2\src\Acme\HelloBundle\Controller\HelloController.php line
>   14. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace? Perhaps you need to add a use statement for one of the following:
>   Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Response,
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response,
>   Doctrine\CouchDB\HTTP\Response.

As I can load the "use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;" class for all my controllers without the need to be including it in each controller

Help please, nedd autoload of HttpFoundation\Response

Thanks

Comment: You need the use statement.  Just the way php namespaces work.  Unless you want to do return new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response() but that is not ideal.

Answer (score 3):

When you use the `use` statement you are not including the file that contains the class, you are aliasing/importing the namespace.

You import the namespace like so:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
```

Or you could  alias a class, for example the Response class could be aliased to SymfonyResponse:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response as SymfonyResponse;
```

Then you can use the new alias in your code:

```
return new SymfonyResponse('<html><body>Hello '.$name.'!</body></html>');
```

If you don't import the class namespace the autoloader will think that you are trying to load a Response class within the current namespace: `Acme\HelloBundle\Controller` which doesn't exist.

Now, if you don't want to add the `use` statement at the top of the file, use the fully qualified name:

```
return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response('<html><body>Hello '.$name.'!</body></html>');
```

I personally would recommend against this as it can get crazy depending on who many classes you are using ...  just add the `use` statement. Some IDEs will add it automatically for you (e.g. PHPStorm).

For more information see

1. [Using namespaces: Aliasing/Importing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)
2. [How to use namespaces, part 1: the basics](http://www.sitepoint.com/php-53-namespaces-basics/)
3. [How to Use PHP Namespaces, Part 2: Importing, Aliases, and Name Resolution](http://www.sitepoint.com/php-namespaces-import-alias-resolution/)
4. [Composer namespaces in 5 minutes](https://jtreminio.com/2012/10/composer-namespaces-in-5-minutes/)

Answer (score 0):

Do what the error message says. Uncomment the use statement that imports the Request class into the current namespace and let the autoloader to its work.

A use statement does not trigger autoload, the file is only included if the class is referenced in executed code.

Comment: In the book Symfony2 not put this class in the controller

Then where I put in the class autoloading "HttpFoundation\Response"??

Thanks

Comment: I want to use the class "HttpFoundation\Response" without included in any controller, what I want is autoload for all the controllers of all bundlers

Comment: What do you mean by include? Do you refer to the `use` statement? You can use the class anywhere you want, als long as php can resolve the correct namespace.